# Rails and authlogic, Not able to solve dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authlogic

This is my Gemfile:

```
gem "rails", "~> 2.3.8"
gem "rake", "0.9.2"
gem 'mysql', '2.8.1'

gem 'aasm', '2.1.5'
gem "authlogic", "2.1.6"
gem "acl9", "0.12.0"
gem "formtastic", "1.2.5"
```

But bundle install reports:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":  
In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 2.3.8) ruby depends on
      activesupport (= 2.3.8) ruby

    authlogic (= 2.1.6) ruby depends on
      activesupport (1.0.0)
```

**UPDATE**

I've tried different combinations of gem versions.
And finally found a row without the version specification... that I didn't saw between comments. So the code snippet above was already correct.

Comment: i don't understand... what's the problem?

Comment: I really don't understand stupid people that do not write a comment, and still give negative votes. Completely useless!

Comment: @MichDart The question doesn't show much research effort into the problem. (Hover over the down arrow to see what it means.) Questions that seem to "dump" a problem without any explanation of **what has been done to try to solve the problem** tend to get downvoted and closed. Please edit the question and explain your position and things you've tried. If you're stuck on something you don't understand, say so. And remember, **downvotes are not personal**.

Comment: Thank you @Substantial for your explanation. I'll try to be more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use those versions?

Why not simply replace

```
gem "authlogic", "2.1.6"
```

with

```
gem "authlogic"
```

and let the bundle solve version dependencies?

Sometimes after doing so in the gemfile you get an error from the bundler and you have to run `bundle update authlogic` before the general `bundle install`

Comment: Hey Fer, i cannot remove the gem version, otherwise I'll encounter compatibility issues with rails2 and other gems. Anyway, I found a gem between comments, at the end of the Gemfile that was wrong. And that fixed the issue. Thank you for your kind comment.